# Listener Pattern via Templates, how to use templated class without specifying template parameter? c++

Tags: c++, templates, listener

I want to implement a Reciever/Publisher class via templates. I am not sure whether templates is the best for this. However, what I got so far is this:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename InType,typename OutType> class Pipe {
    public:
        void addListener(Pipe<OutType,???> l){
            listener.push_back(l);
        }
        virtual OutType process(InType)=0;
        void Fill(InType value){
            OutType outValue = process(value);
            for (int i=0;i<listener.size();i++){
                listener[i]->Fill(outValue);
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<Pipe<OutType,???>*> listener;
};
```

A Pipe should allow listener with different OutTypes. Actually, it does not need to know the OutType of its listeners, as the process() is called by the listeners. However, I have to put an template parameter. Is there something wrong with my approach? Or is there a way to avoid specifying the OutType of the listeners?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26213392/1782465), some of the same principles could apply.

Comment: The main problem with your approach is that you are considering that all listener  classes have to be `Pipe`, when in fact they only need to be a "receiving end". You should probably define a super class which only carries the "listening" part of the `Pipe` class (so the later would inherit it). Or do you have a good reason for that design choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Pipe<InType, OutType>` inherit a common base class depending only on `InType`:

```
template <typename InType>
class PipeBase {
public:
    virtual ~PipeBase() = default;
    virtual void Fill(InType value) = 0;
};

template <typename InType, typename OutType>
class Pipe : public PipeBase<InType> {
public:
    void addListener(PipeBase<OutType>* l){
        listener.push_back(l);
    }

    void Fill(InType value) { ... }

private:
    std::vector<PipeBase<OutType>*> listener;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5a9ce837f707e06)

Answer (score 1):

The source of your confusion is conflating the concept of Listener, something that is notified of an event, with Pipe - something that is notified of an event, performs some processing, and then notifies a set of Listeners of the results of that processing. In this model, a Pipe is-a Listener, but a Listener is not necessarily a Pipe.

I'd suggest that you (1) allow any callable object that can accept `OutType` to be a listener, (2) have `Pipe` accept input via `operator()` so it is a valid listener for `InType`. You can then use `std::function<void(OutType)>` to erase the type of listeners, and while you're at it, use `std::function<OutType(Intype)>` to erase the type of the transform function:

```
template <typename InType, typename OutType>
class Pipe {
public:
  Pipe(std::function<OutType(InType)> transform) :
    transform_(std::move(transform)) {}

  // For lvalues, return reference to *this for chaining.
  Pipe& addListener(std::function<void(OutType)> f) & {
    listeners_.push_back(std::move(f));
    return *this;
  }

  // For rvalues, return *this by value for chaining.
  Pipe addListener(std::function<void(OutType)> f) && {
    listeners_.push_back(std::move(f));
    return std::move(*this);
  }

  void operator() (InType value) {
    const auto outValue = transform_(std::move(value));
    for (auto& listener : listeners_) {
      listener(outValue);
    }
  }

private:
  std::function<OutType(InType)> transform_;
  std::vector<std::function<void(OutType)>> listeners_;
};
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0af3110cc1b304b)**

Comment: Actually I came up with a similar solution. I found that in my case it really makes more sense to have a "Provider" and a "Listener", where the listener is meant to be inherited and the provider to be used as a class member, such that one object can provide several different messages to listeners.